# javascript number too big for modulo

Tags: javascript, calculator, modulo

Just a simple question.

I am trying to calculate something in js:

```
print(pow(49, 37) % 77)
```

this will print 22 instead of what it schould really be (14).

I am just not sure if this is beacuse of it being too big to calculate accuratly or if I am missing something and just did it wrong.

If it being too big is the cause, how can I work auround it? (btw changing it to BigNumber wont solve the problem)

Thanks :)

Comment: "*I am just not sure if this is beacuse of it being too big to calculate accuratly*" [the result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=49+%5E+37) is `344552147465294110719732986332367243247925798357929806000836849` which is *orders of magnitude* bigger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (`9007199254740991`)

Comment: Yes, it is too big to fit IEEE754 exactly. Use bigint instead `49n**37n % 77n`  Is it python code thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common operation in cryptography
What you can do is to compute the power yourself iteratively, and at each iteration you reduce it `mod 77`. The function `powmod` below is what you have to do, all the rest is to make the snippet interactive.

```js
function powmod(a, b, mod){
  if(b < 1){
    return 1;
  }
  const t = powmod(a, b >> 1, mod);
  if(b & 1){
    return (a * t * t) % mod;
  }else{
    return (t * t) % mod;
  }
}

const a = document.getElementById('a');
const b = document.getElementById('b');
const c = document.getElementById('c');
const d = document.getElementById('d');
function update(){
  d.value = powmod(parseInt(a.value), parseInt(b.value), parseInt(c.value))
}

[a,b,c].map(e => e.addEventListener('change', update))
update()
```

```html
pow(<input type="number" min="0" max="999999" step="1" id="a" value="49">, 
<input type="number" min="0" max="999999" step="1" id="b" value="37">) % 
<input type="number" min="0" max="999999" step="1" id="c" value="77"> = 
<input type="number" min="0" max="999999" step="1" id="d" disabled>
```