# Why does Java Sript give me back the same results for (97**13)%77 and (104**13)%77?

Tags: javascript, math

I have a Math problem in Java Script.
Java Sript says that `(104**13)%77 == (97**13)%77`. But i don´t know why, when i copy and paste it in Python it doens´t say they are equal. Python says: `(97**13)%77 = 69` and `(104**13)%77 = 48`.

Comment: [`97**13` is](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=97**13) `67302709016557486028618977` which is *much* larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (`9007199254740991`)

Comment: Similar: [javascript number too big for modulo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66459806)